# Remove first character from a string in data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am doing an analysis in r on tweets imported from a python script and have accidentally included the letter "b" before each tweet. It is the first character in one of the columns in the data frame. I have managed to clean up the tweets otherwise using the "stringr" package, does anyone know how to change this, in other words just get rid of the first character in the column usertweet? Here is some example code:

```
username = c("user1", "user2") 
usertweet= c("b something", "b something something") 
tweetsdf <-data.frame(username,usertweet)
```

Comment: at least 5 down-votes are you kidding me? I'm starting to feel embarrassed to be a part of this community

Comment: some loser whose feeling i have hurt has started downvoting some of my answers. you are only proving my point

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We can use `substring`

```
tweetsdf$usertweet <- substring(tweetsdf$usertweet, 3)
```

---

Or use `sub`

```
sub("\\S+\\s+", "", tweetsdf$usertweet)
```

Comment: so you got 3 downvotes for this answer?

Comment: I am so sorry if I have gotten anyone in trouble! Thanks for the answer though it fixed my problem!